# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset order_fk

Tags: php

I don't find a reason why the offset is considered illegal in the code snippet. Any suggestion to fix this with an explanation why the error occurs is greatly appreciated.

```
    foreach ($my_return->refund_items as $key => $my_refund_item) {
        $refund_item_info = $my_return->get_line_item_info($my_refund_item['lineitem_fk']);
        if ($refund_item_info['order_fk'] != 0)
            $my_refund_item['sku'] = $refund_item_info['sku'];
        $refund_items_array[] = $my_refund_item;
    }
```

Comment: you need to first check using the print_r($refund_item_info) or check there is order_fk key exist or not in $refund_item_info array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question why the warning "PHP Warning: Illegal string offset order_fk" is thrown. This warning indicates that probably you are treating a string object as associative array. Although you could treat string as array where index can be applied like `[0]` or `[1]` to get individual characters from string but not as associative array where key is string.

Now to solve you problem, as Rasik mentioned in comment, first you need to print `$refund_item_info` to check what is exact content of it also check its type by `echo gettype($refund_item_info)`.

Additionally to let you know, check if value is json, since json is considered as string, so you need to convert a json string into array by `$str = json_decode($str, true);` before accessing its keys.

Hope it helps you.
Thanks

Comment: I shall do as advised. Accepted your answer as it enlightens me on the underlying concepts. Thanks Abdul.

Comment: Most Welcome :)